# Global object for Javascript to interact with Safari plug-in

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, safari, webkit

The issue is that I've written a Safari plug-in ([Growler](http://adityamukherjee.com/oldblog/archives/1535)) that allows web applications to send Growl notifications by calling Javascript functions. However, at the moment the way it is written, people need to use `<embed>` to initialise the plug-in so that Javascript can begin using it (something I picked up from Apple's examples).

I was wondering if there was a way I could define something like `window.<pluginName>` so that they didn't have to embed it everytime? That'll allow a lot of sites to begin using it without changing any code.

I've looked at a lot of examples and documentation, and two things came up — 'WebView' and 'WebScriptObject'. I'm pretty new to this, so I'm not really sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to write a WebKit plug-in that doesn't handle a content type. That's why so many Safari “plug-ins” or “extensions” (including GrowlSafari) are implemented as input manager hacks.

The way you've done it is the only reliable, safe, supported, and not doomed way to do it.

Comment: Really? That's bad, because that also means there's no real way to check if my plug-in exists (which makes it harder to gracefully degrade). Any mighty brain waves in this regard?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Unlike Firefox, WebKit implements the `navigator.plugins` rather nicely.